# How can I editable false description or sort description magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, ui

I have try but it is not working for me any have idea about this?

```
<fieldset name="content">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
         <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
       </item>
     </argument>
   </fieldset>  
<fieldset name="content">
            <field name="container_description">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean no one can able to add content to description field?

Comment: Yes prasant bhai  exactly

Comment: @PrashantValanda have you any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your form file and change your input field text to label as per below code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `disabled` to `false` for the `content` field as well and try again

```
<fieldset name="content">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
             <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           </item>
         </argument>
       </fieldset>  
    <fieldset name="content">
                <field name="container_description">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
```